# How can I keep track of original character positions in a string across transformations?

Tags: java, parsing, string, antlr, lexer

I'm working on an anti-plagiarism project for my CS class.  This involves detecting plagiarism in computer science courses (programming assignments), through a technique described ["Winnowing: Local Algorithms for Document Fingerprinting."](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigmod03.pdf)

Basically, I'm taking a group of programming assignments. Lets say one of the assignments looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // declare a variable called someVar
        int someVar = 0;
    }
}
```

This needs to get run through a front-end, lexical analysis portion to strip out features of the code we don't want.  In this instance I want to rename all *Identifier names* to the constant "V" and strip all *comments* from the code.

To do this, we will use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) and existing grammars for various languages to generate the appropriate lexers.

The end result is this:

```
public class V
{
    public static void V(String[] V)
    {
        int V = 0;
    }
}
```

We then strip all whitespace to get:

```
publicclassV{publicstaticvoidV(String[]V){intV=0;}}
```

This string is then broken down into k-grams of a preset size.  For example say k  = 5 (in reality it would be larger):

```
publi ublic blicc liccl iccla ... =0;}}
```

Here is the problem:

Each k-gram is hashed with a rolling hash function and is supposed to be recorded with their *original character position* in the source text.  A k-gram hash and character position together form a fingerprint.

How can I keep track of a k-grams original position in the source text across all the front-end stripping of identifiers, comments and white-space?

This is essential for the final phase of the program where you highlight matches in pairs of documents in the original source text.  In order to highlight the matches of k-gram hashes I need to know where that k-gram started and ended in the original source.

Comment: See also this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303924/how-can-i-keep-track-of-character-positions-after-i-remove-elements-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

The ANTLR lexers keep track of token positions in the source stream.

- Move comments and whitespace to the hidden channel
- Set the `Text` property of identifier tokens to "V"
- Run your rolling hash against a `CommonTokenStream`, looking at the `Text` property of each token.

With the tokens intact from start to end, you'll have the mapping preserved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, why are using this step:

This string is then broken down into k-grams of a preset size. For example say k = 5 (in reality it would be larger):
publi ublic blicc liccl iccla ... =0;}}

I mean why is this required for Plagiarism Detection?

Comment: Read the PDF link I gave above.  Basically, by splitting the source code into k-grams and hashing them you can detect matches between documents despite re-ordering and whitespace.